# Cajoling in Server Side

Tags: javascript, xss, google-caja

I read some page of google-caja wiki and interest to use that.
My view of caja is that We can send some chunk of html(for example  tag) to google-caja's server(cajoling service) and that cajole that html and content javascript then send to our page. finally loaded google-caja's javaScript provide virtual DOM for content javascript(in tag div). And many other option for it(for example disabling tag content js).

I want to use this capability(cajole)  in server side. Load some html chunk. Then pass it as a String to caja.And insert returned cajole String with necessary js(for apply limitation) to my JAVA web application response.

-Html chunk which should be cajole loaded in **server side** or provided from DB and is A **String**
-My web application's language is **JAVA**.

which jars and jses file needed?
Start from which function?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`web.xml`](http://code.google.com/p/google-caja/source/browse/trunk/web.xml?r=5066) used in the Caja playground shows that the [`CajolingServlet`](http://code.google.com/p/google-caja/source/browse/trunk/src/com/google/caja/service/CajolingServlet.java) and `PrecajoleInfoServlet` are used to get the service up and running.

The [ANT build file](http://code.google.com/p/google-caja/source/browse/trunk/build.xml#640) lists the set of JARs you need.  The main one is `ant-jars/pluginc.jar` and the rest are 3rd-party dependencies.

[google-caja-discuss](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/google-caja-discuss) is a good place for questions too.

Comment: Than you so much. I create caja project in eclipse, add source and add necessary jar files. It's compiled and run. I should read and analysis source code.